# Is $p(\heartsuit \cap A)=p(\heartsuit)\times p(A)$ still valid for this unclear combinatoric argumentation?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> What is the probability that an Ace Heart is drawn from a deck of playing cards (consisting of 52 cards)?

The teacher answered as follows.

\begin{align}
p(\heartsuit \cap A) 
 &= p(\heartsuit)\times p(A)\\
 &= \frac{13}{52}\times \frac{4}{52}\\
 &= \frac{1}{52}
\end{align}

## Question

His combinatoric argumentation is not obvious here even though the answer is correct. It looks like he draws two cards with replacement (shuffle the deck, take one card,  return it to the deck, shuffle, and take one card again).

In my answer below, the combinatoric argumentation is "a card can be regarded as a Cartesian product of a suit (of 4 kinds) and a number (of 13 kinds)". I choose a suit first, choose a number, and print the card. :-)

\begin{align}
p(\heartsuit \cap A) 
 &= p(\heartsuit)\times p(A)\\
 &= \frac{1}{4}\times \frac{1}{13}\\
 &= \frac{1}{52}
\end{align}

Correct me whether he is wrong or not.

Comment: As your teacher what probability he'd compute if the club, diamond, and spade aces were all replaced by jokers.  See how he struggles with that!  Be prepared to explain to him the notion of independence.

Comment: That's a rather dubious and strange way of answering a question that has a much simpler answer.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen:  Having taught statistics in one of the world's elite statistics departments, I think my admittedly incomplete "answer" will force the student *and* the teacher to understand the material more deeply.  Let them discuss (and argue, if needed).  I stand by my "educational" approach.  But how is it "dubious"?

Comment: It looks like \begin{align} 2x&=4\\x&=4-2\\x&=2\end{align}. Correct by accident.

Comment: You can make an argument here that it's acceptable to regard suits and value as independent here but like David says, it's not very robust

Comment: @DavidG.Stork If I were arguing with you I would have @-d you. I'm referring to the teacher's answer. I'm the plus 1 on your comment.

Comment: The core issue here is independence.  Is choosing an Ace and choosing a heart *independent*?  In some cases yes... but this need not be the case.  Clarifying this core topic will help both student and teacher.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen:  Oh...  your comment came immediately after mine, so naturally I assumed...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Thank you for confirming that he is not correct. So it is time to delete my question. :-)

Comment: Oh... I would leave it up, as it is instructive.  But of course this is your call.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: OK. I leave it as it is. It might be useful for others as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Combinatorial:**  There is one Ace of Hearts in a deck of 52 cards, so probability of getting it is $1/52.$

**Probability rule for intersection of independent events:** Noting that Denominations and Suits are independent in drawing from a standard deck 
$$P(A \cap H) = P(A)P(H) = (1/13)(1/4) = 1/52.$$

One can't answer in a way that helps student without knowing where they are in the course.